# Oracle APEX - how to find out which pages of the application use a specific shared component?

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I want to make a list of shared components that are not used by the application. Is it possible to do in oracle apex?

I also want to create a report of all the places where a particular component is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's specific for component, but you need to look for Utilization.

For example:

App Builder > Your Application > Utilities > Application Dashboard

For specific LOV you have Usage on the right pane of Details.

For Authorization Scheme there is tab Utilization.

Same for Templates > Utilization > References > clickable numbers of items.

Comment: I went to Application Dashboard and I can only see how many of a particular type of component are there in the application, not how many times a component is used